# Python | Ordenar lista multidimensional según elemento en posición que nos interese

Tags: python, lista, array-bidimensional

No consigo ordenar una lista multidimensional utilizando el elemento que en la posición que me interese.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejemplo anterior, lo siguiente, se debería ordenar de forma ascendente según el elemento en la posición 3: `400, 64, 90` (quedando: `64,90,400`):

Con la fución `sorter()` creo que se ordena listas simples, pero ¿las mutidimensionales?

```
lista=[[3,17,400],[5,2,64],[8,1,90]]
```

Debería quedar:

```
lista=[[5,2,64],[8,1,90],[3,17,400]]
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tanto `sorted()` como el método `.sort()` de las listas permite añadir una función que indique la clave por la que hacer la ordenación.

Como quieres ordenar por el tercer elemento, podemos hacerlo así:

```py
lista = [[3,17,400],[5,2,64],[8,1,90]]

lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Como es bastante común querer ordenar por un elemento de la lista, el módulo [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html) ofrece varios generadores que se pueden usar con el argumento `key` que son bastante más eficiente.

Por ejemplo, para crear una función que obtenga el tercer elemento podemos hacerlo con [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```py
from operator import itemgetter

lista = [[3,17,400],[5,2,64],[8,1,90]]

lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=itemgetter(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres ordenar las sublistas según el número que le proporciones.

Podemos hacerlo con un método y que a través del método le pases como parámetro la posición por la cuál quieres ordenar las sublistas:

Código si ordenamos por la posición 1:

```
def ordenarPorPosicionSubLista(lista: list, posicionOrdenar: int) -> list:
    return(sorted(lista, key = lambda elemento: elemento[posicionOrdenar-1]))

lista=[[3,17,400],[5,2,64],[8,1,90]]

print(ordenarPorPosicionSubLista(lista, 1))
```

Resultado:

```
[[3, 17, 400], [5, 2, 64], [8, 1, 90]]
```

Si ordenamos por la posición 2:

```
print(ordenarPorPosicionSubLista(lista, 2))
```

Resultado:

```
[[8, 1, 90], [5, 2, 64], [3, 17, 400]]
```

Creo que sería la opción más sencilla, sino tendríamos que utilizar varios bucles y se haría muy largo e ilegible el código.